Building a statically-linked pysqlite3 library
I am trying to compile and import SQLite3 into Python3 by following Building a statically-linked library, however I can't get it to work. I have compiled from source, copied .c and .h files, run python setup.py build_static build, but it's not working.
❯ find . -name "_sqlite3*.so"
./build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/pysqlite3/_sqlite3.cpython-312-darwin.so

❯ python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload', '/Users/myusername/Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages', '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages', '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pysqlite3-0.5.4-py3.12-macosx-14.0-arm64.egg', '/opt/homebrew/opt/python-tk@3.12/libexec']

However, then trying to import it does not work:
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Sandbox/sqlite3ttt/pysqlite3/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
  File "/Users/username/Sandbox/sqlite3ttt/pysqlite3/pysqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pysqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/username/Sandbox/sqlite3ttt/pysqlite3/pysqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pysqlite3._sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite3._sqlite3'


Try this: py -m pip install libsqlite3-dev

@toyotaSupra, are you sure this is correct? I am on MacOs.

The error is due to the fact that in the current directory, there is a subdirectory named pysqlite3 which hides build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312/pysqlite3.
From within the directory you ran find . -name "_sqlite3*.so", execute following commands :
export PYTHONPATH="$PWD/build/lib.macosx-14.0-arm64-cpython-312"
cd /tmp
python3 -c "from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3" # <- should not print error


this was it!! Thank you. Did you see it based on the error message that there was a subdirectory pysqlite3?

Yes, also based on the output of python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" which has '' as first element.
